# PHP-MySQL Link retrieves OK but moves link in table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to implement an Ajax call to refresh part of a page when the user clicks on a link in a table. The data retrieves OK but if the user scrolled down to the link, it moves the table data to the top every time so they lose their place. Example at https://usafcca.org/memorial

Scroll down and click on a link toward the bottom, when the right side refreshes it move you back to the top. Any hints on how to fix this appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is your code? Please consider reading how to post a good question and a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your links, alter the onclick...

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajax_loader(XXX);return false;">
```